# How can I set window type hints on a ClutterStage?

Tags: python, xorg, clutter

Is there any way to make a standalone `ClutterStage` use `TYPE_HINT_DOCK` (and be borderless), with python? Perhaps by manipulating the window with Xlib?

Answer (score 1):

I also strongly suggest to use clutter-gtk. It's python bindings have not been removed from Ubuntu.

However, clutter is now using gobject introspection for it's python bindings instead of generating them ([simple example](http://wiki.clutter-project.org/wiki/ExamplePython)).

The new package name in Ubuntu is now `gir1.2-clutter-gtk-0.10` instead of python-clutter-something. You can get an overview of other clutter based bindings with `apt-cache search clutter gir`.

This also means that nearly every gnome project now has python bindings, just do `apt-cache search gir1`.

Comment: clutter-gtk has been removed in 12.04, I believe. Also, I use ArchLinux, not Ubuntu, and I have found clutter **incredibly** unstable when used through GI, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to retrieve the Stage XID and set the hints manually.

alternatively, you could use Clutter-Gtk, and the Gdk API, instead of using Xlib directly.

Comment: Could you explain how? I'm getting a bit lost in Xlib's documentation.

Comment: you'll need to change the _XA_MOTIF_WM_HINTS property on the stage window, following the ICCCM and the EWMH specifications. it's pretty boring Xlib stuff, so my suggestion is to use clutter-gtk if at all possible.

Comment: I am trying to get rid of the cluttergtk dependencies if at all possible, since Ubuntu no longer provides this in the default repos. (and that's where most of the linux users are these days...). Also, the problem I'm having right now is actually acquiring the Window object from Xlib.

Comment: @crazedpsyc: You should be able to retrieve XLib Window with `clutter_x11_get_stage_window ()` and then add hints to it using XLib calls.